# Any way to instruct Entity Framework to map from column to Model property in code-first, table-per-hierarchy approach?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, table-per-hierarchy

We are using `Entity Framework 6.1` in our MVC application, using `code-first` and `table-per-hierarchy` approach since we are developing from scratch and we think this way is suitable for fast development. But now I have a question: say I have one base class and three sub classes, which look like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SubClassOne : BaseClass
{
    public double Volume { get; set; }        
}

public class SubClassTwo : BaseClass
{
    public double Volume { get; set; }
}

public class SubClassThree : BaseClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

When using default settings, EF will create 6 columns for the database table: ID, Name, Volume, Volume1, Number and Discriminater. The Volume column will only be used for SubClassOne and Volume1 will for SubClassTwo, Number only for SubClassThree.

I don't care too much about the "waste" of database row spaces. But here is one thing that's bothering me: if I am a new developer and is now looking at the database directly, the names of "Volume" and "Volume1" confuse me. I know on the code side there is SubClassOne and SubClassTwo and both have a property named "Volume". But I could never know which column is for which class. So my question is, is there any way to instruct Entity Framework (e.g., using attribute) that both `SubClassOne.Volume` and `SubClassTwo.Volume` are mapped to `Volume` column in the database. (another benefit is I reduce one column but that's not my main target).

I guess if I don't use Entity Framework, code-first, or table-per-hierarchy, and design the tables and especially the DAL myself, I can have full control and achieve this. But how about now?

Comment: do you want to have a BaseClass table in DB?

Comment: @MicahelMao Yes since I am using table-per-hierarchy and `BaseClass` is the base class, my table will be named BaseClasses and it contains records for both `BaseClass` and derived classes objects

Comment: Have you tried this public abstract class BaseClass

Comment: You can use Attribute [Column("Volume1")] and [Column("Volume2")] to both Class, so it can map to related Database Column and You have same Property name "Volume"

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I tested it and it worked! I might need to do some more test but at least I was able to load property values for both classes under the same column "Volume". Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Attribute [Column("Volume1")] and [Column("Volume2")] to both Class, so it can map to related Database Column and You have same Property name "Volume".

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SubClassOne : BaseClass
{
    [Column("Volume1")]   
    public double Volume { get; set; }        
}

public class SubClassTwo : BaseClass
{
    [Column("Volume2")] 
    public double Volume { get; set; }
}

public class SubClassThree : BaseClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine.If any doubt then tell me.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I ask (and I made a mistake in the original post), although your answer points to the correct direction. My original problem is, if I use default setting, EF will generate a column called "Volume" for `SubClassOne.Volume` and another column called "Volume1" for `SubClassTwo`. I find it confusing since I won't be able to insert a row directly manually since I don't know which column is for which class property. So what I want is, since both properties have the same name, I want only one column in the database and EF would query this column for both properties

Comment: And your suggestion of using `ColumnAttribute` definitely works here. Just need to use `[Column("Volume")]`.